# Does bindService() with BIND_AUTO_CREATE always creates new service instance?

Tags: android, service

In `onCreate()` of main activity I call `bindService()` with `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` flag, and call `unbindService()` in `onDestroy()`. Then I start Activity, finish it and start again.

I see that services's `onCreate()`, `onBind()` and `onUnbind()` are called sequentially.
When I start activity second time, service's `onCreate()` and `onBind()` are also called, but it's **another service instance**, it has another `this`.

I expect, that service stay alive after unbinding, and the second onBind() will bind to the same service. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 3):

> I expect, that service stay alive after unbinding, and the second onBind() will bind to the same service.

No. A service will be destroyed if:

- You unbind from each bound connection, and
- Nothing has called `startService()` on the service

In your case, you are unbinding from the service, and since nothing has started the service, the service is destroyed. Your next `bindService()` call will create a new instance, since there is no running instance at that moment.